# While loop using a probability density function

Tags: r

I want to make a while loop that, until n is not equal to 105, it takes a random value x, and if the value x respects some restrictions, it store that value.
The x has to be between 15 and 33
It also simulates a variable num that has to be a random variable from a uniform distribution betwenn 0 and 1.

```
library(ggplot2)
dev.new()
n = 0
set.seed(1684)
x = seq(15, 33, by = 0.1)
f <- function(x) {
  out <- ifelse(
    x < 15 | 33 < x,
    0,
    ifelse(
      15 <= x & x <= 24,
      (2*(x-15))/((33-15)*(24-15)),
      ifelse(
        24 < x & x <= 33,
        (2*(33-x))/((33-15)*(33-24)),
        NA_real_
      )))
  if (any((is.na(out) | is.nan(out)) & (!is.na(x) & !is.nan(x)))) {
    warning("f(x) undefined for some input values")
  }
  out
}

while (n != 105) {
  n = n + 1
  x1 = runif(1, min = 15 , max = 33)
  num = runif(1, min = 0 , max = 1)
  if ((num < (f(x1)/2/(33-15))) && (num == (18*(f(x1)/2)))) {
    
    x_accept = c(x_accept, x1)
  }
}
```

I've made this but it doesn't work, the x_accept is just an empty list

Comment: The probability of meeting the condition `num == (18*(f(x1)/2)))` is vanishingly small. I suspect this is why `x_accept` is empty. Also, I don't see where `x_accept` is defined before `x_accept = c(x_accept, x1)`.

Comment: @jblood94 I know the x_accept = c(x_accept, x1) is wrong, I just don't know how to make a loop that concatenates numbers into a vector collum, I previously used matlab and we did something of similar to this so I tried it

Comment: You can initialize it before the `while` loop with `x_accept <- numeric(0)`. But there's still the problem that `num` is basically never going to equal `18*f(x1)/2`.